# Now() Value in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to set the expression `#Now() + CreateTimeSpan('30','0','0','0')#` in a cookie and manipulating the values in a JS function.

The value of the expression is being displayed as `41720.406`?  What does this value mean?

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: What is the reason for using a time span object? To add or subtract dates, just use the standard [date functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6ddb.html).

Comment: If you want to see what that number means, apply a dateformat to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use `DateAdd()` instead.  So use `DateAdd('d', 30, Now())`.

```
<cfset x = DateAdd('d', 30, now())>
<cfoutput>#toScript(x, "time")#</cfoutput>
```

output:

```
time = new Date(2014, 2, 22, 2, 36, 26);
```

Answer (score 4):

> 41720.406? What does this value mean?

To answer your question, apparently it represents a number of days from the CF epoch ie 1899-12-30, plus or minus time zone offsets.

```
 <cfscript>
    cfEpoch  = createDate(1899, 12, 30);

    // add number of whole days ie 41720
    finalDate  = dateAdd("d", 41720, cfEpoch ); 
    // add partial days ie partialDay * millisecondsPerDay
    finalDate  = dateAdd("l", 0.406 * 86400000, finalDate);   

    // Result: Today's date and time plus 30 days
    writeOutput( "finalDate="& dateConvert("local2UTC", finalDate) );
 </cfscript>
```

Having said that, it is much simpler to use [date functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6986) as others suggested, rather than mucking with time span objects.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the cfepoch info. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned cookies, it's worth pointing out that dates for cookies use a specific format, i.e. `Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT`

This is not how CF formats dates by default - when you output `#SomeDate#` the format used is `{ts '1970-01-01 00:00:01'}` instead.

Here's a function that returns a date as a string in the format cookies use:

```
<cffunction name="formatCookieDate" returntype="String" output=false access="public">
    <cfargument name="DateTime" type="Date"   default=#Now()# />
    <cfargument name="isUtc"    type="String" default=false   />

    <cfif NOT Arguments.isUtc >
        <cfset Arguments.DateTime = DateConvert('local2utc',Arguments.DateTime) />
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn DateTimeFormat( Arguments.DateTime ,'E, dd Mmm yyyy HH:nn:ss' ) & ' GMT' />
</cffunction>
```

You can use it like this:

```
formatCookieDate( Now() + 30 )
```

Whilst some prefer using [DateAdd](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/dateadd), it is perfectly valid to add days directly - though you might want to consider if you're actually wanting to add 30 days versus adding 1 month.

NOTE: On versions prior to CF10 you'll need to split the [DateTimeFormat](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/datetimeformat) into [DateFormat](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/dateformat) and [TimeFormat](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/timeformat) and update the masks accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter. This is what my next roadblock had been since yesterday.

Comment: *consider if you're actually wanting to add 30 days versus adding 1 month* If it is the former, using `+` is sufficient. Otherwise, go with `DateAdd`, as it handles all of the date logic gotchas for you.